# Examples of C programs with long execution time

Tags: c++, c, execution-time

Please suggest me some examples of C programs that have long execution time, apart from the usual sorting and recursion. I want to analyze the execution times of code and would like to use some programs that have considerable execution time, not just in milliseconds.

Comment: I guess you can pick up any NP problem and have programs that run for very very very long times. :)

Comment: My OS has a "long execution time".

Comment: Actually sorting isn't long...

Comment: Compression software comes to mind. bzip2 is such a program and comes with full source code.

Comment: @pst well, for me nlogn isn't "long" :) what about "compute the permutations of an array"? that's a nice exponential one :P

Comment: @alestanis actually super-exponential. Exponential would mean `2^theta(x)` which it isn't.

Comment: There are lots of them, especially if they are deliberately written as infinite loops. A few examples: One, the linux kernel, our servers haven't been rebooted for almost 3 years now. Another example is the Apache web server (any server actually) our web servers are restarted roughly once a month.

Comment: @alestanis more exactly, "enumerate the permutations of x elements" is `2^theta(x log x)`

Comment: Graphics rendering of complex scenes takes a lot of time. I think POVray is implemented in C

Answer (score 2):

Implement a NP class algorithm,for example factoring numbers. 
Anyway,a lot of ideas are listed here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems

Answer (score 1):

Implement any of the problems from http://projecteuler.net/. Quite a lot of them, especially with a naive implementation, can be computationally intensive.